# Jquery height tag giving different height in mozilla and chrome

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery's

```
$("#addNewCompanyBefore").height();
```

for getting height of div but it is giving different value in Mozilla browser and chrome browser. In Mozilla it is 506px but in chrome it is giving 453px. What can be the reason and what can the possible or alternative solution for it?

I have also tried jQuery's innerHeight function but no gain so far.

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Comment: I checked the function but no difference

Comment: do you happen to have box-sizing:border-box applied to the element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have images inside your div ?
This could some time happen when the div contents are not fully loaded when you check its height.

Not sure if it will work or not. But can you try putting `$("#addNewCompanyBefore").height();` in `jQuery(window).load()` to make sure that its contents are fully loaded when you check its height.